# lower bound for sum of (squared) distances under a minimum distance restriction

Tags: discrete-geometry, packing-and-covering

I am trying to solve a packing problem in discrete geometry and it would be useful to know the answer to the following problem.

Let $A_1$, $A_2$,..., $A_n$ be $n$ points in the Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Suppose that $A_iA_j\ge 1$ for all $1\le i<j\le n$, where $A_iA_j$ denotes the Euclidean distance between $A_i$ and $A_j$. We say such a point set is 
$separated$.

Consider the following quantities

$$f(n)=\min \sum_{1\le i<j\le n} A_iA_j^2,\quad \text{and} \quad g(n)=\min \sum_{1\le i<j\le n} A_iA_j.$$
Here the minimums are taken over all separated point sets in the plane.

It is obvious that $f(2)=g(2)=1$ and $f(3)=g(3)=3$. How about $f(4)$ and $g(4)$? I believe $f(4)=8$ and $g(4)=5+\sqrt{3}$ but I cannot prove any of these. What happens for $n=5, 6, 7\ldots$?

Has this problem been considered before? I found some references for the dual $maximization$ problem, when the points are at distance $at \,\, most$ $1$ from each other, but nothing for this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.